# Jenkins Build Failure Analyzer plugin regex multiline

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Jenkins [Build Failure Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer) plugin trying to match a multiline pattern in the build log.  The text I want to match in the log is:

```
Total time: 1 minute 45 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
```

The regex I am using is:

```
(?s)Total(.*)failure
```

Seems pretty simple, but this is not matching the lines above.

Another example I am working with is:

```
     [java] ACTION REQUIRED
     [java] 
     [java] I want to match this line
     [java] as well as this line
     [java] 
     [java] CONSOLE LOG
```

The regex for this is:

```
(?s)REQUIRED(.*)CONSOLE
```

Also produces no results.

Comment: FYI, cross-ref, as I get the failure plugin mixed up with this one:  This plugin uses Java Regex, per its docs , to compute a left nav bar. "Collapsing Console Sections Plugin - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki" ; ; https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the log contains further text, even if it's whitespace (or newlines).

Remember, the [plugin uses Pattern.match()](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer#BuildFailureAnalyzer-Knowledgebase) so it has to match the entire "line". So perhaps try:

```regex
(?s)Total(.*)failure.*
```

To be a little more specific, you could do end with \s* to just match trailing whitespace:

```regex
(?s)Total(.*)failure\s*
```

Comment: Good thought, but that isn't matching either...I'm starting to wonder if there is a bug in the plugin.

Comment: Well it sure wouldn't be the first buggy plugin... A couple of other things to try: a .* at the beginning (if there are any non-printable characters before the line begins) just to get it to match at all, and, unlikely, but is your logging colourised - i.e. are there ANSI codes in there? They're not much fun for regexes, especially if they're being correctly interpreted by the [ANSI color plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin)

Comment: Also good thoughts, but the .* at the beginning didn't help and we aren't using the ANSI color plugin.  From what I can tell there are no non-printing characters either.

Answer (score -2):

The Build Analyzer Plugin uses Pattern.match against single lines - you're attempting to match a multiline string.

From [the wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer):

> The Build Log Indication searches through the build log, one line at a
>   time, for a regular expression.

Comment: There is also an option for a multiline match as well though.

Comment: Thanks - you're right, although there's no mention of it on the wiki page. It was added in version 1.7.0 (released Apr 1, 2014), with a bug fix in 1.9.0.